# How to align button on wpf treeview

Tags: wpf, treeview

Hi i am looking for a way to align the buttons in my treeview so that it will look like in the same column even if it is in any level.
Eg:

```
Item1 [Button]
 Item2 [Button]
Item3[Button]
```

i want it to look like

```
Item1  [Button]
 Item2 [Button]
Item3  [Button]
```

Any way that i can do this..?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, take a look at this blog entry [Horizontal stretch on TreeViewItems](https://leecampbell.com/2009/01/14/horizontal-stretch-on-treeviewitems).  The default ControlTemplate for TreeViewItem does not allow the header content to stretch, which you will need it to do.  Use the TreeViewItem Style that the author recommends, but change

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
```

to

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
```

Now you will have a TreeViewItem where the header content stretches across the entire width of the TreeViewItem.  To get the TreeViewItem to render with text plus a button, use the ItemTemplate property of the TreeView.  If you just want the buttons right-aligned, you could use a DockPanel:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding ...}"/>
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="{Binding ...}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

If the contents of the buttons may have variable size and you want them all to have the same width, use a Grid with SharedSizeScope.  Set `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` in the TreeView and then in your ItemTemplate do something like this:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Buttons"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ...}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding ...}"/>
        </Grid>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really know the intrinsic behaviour of Tree View. But the article helps.